# Distorted image with ImageIcon in JButton or JLabel

Tags: java, jbutton, imageicon

I'm making a panel with some buttons and images.
For i.e.

```
url = ImageIO.read(Electroneddas.class.getResourceAsStream("/Img/disk_out.png"));
ImageIcon t=new ImageIcon(url);
                        
JButton bl=new JButton(t);
```

but the image in the button is resized and not shown at 1: 1 scale
[screenshot compared to actual image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwON7.png)

Thanks

EDIT

Complete Test code

```
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    
    public Test() {
        JPanel p=new JPanel();
        BufferedImage url;
        try {
            url = ImageIO.read(Test.class.getResourceAsStream("circle.png"));
            JButton bs=new JButton(new ImageIcon(url));
            
            p.add(bs);
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        add(p);
        
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Test t=new Test();
    }

}
```

Result:
[Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwON7.png)

Original image:
[Circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDyuF.png)

Comment: Are you running your application on Windows with monitor scaling > 100%?

Comment: No, it's the same size

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc yes, that was the problem, a 125% scaling. I've resolved with VM parameter -Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!
The problem was due to the 125% magnification set in Windows.
It now works well with VM parameter -Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1